# parallel program compiling error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mpi

I write a parallel code that I can compile it and run it under win7 but now I have to run it under linux ubuntu 11.04 when I compile my code I get this error:

usr/bin/ld :cannot find -lcr

collect2:ld returned 1 exit status

my compiler is mpicxx and I use mpich2.
my code has about 3000 lines but I use the following code for testing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int mynode, totalnodes;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode);
    cout << "Hello world from process " << mynode;
    cout << " of " << totalnodes << endl;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

and I use this command for compiling it `mpicxx hello.cpp`

Comment: what is the `cr` library and why are you linking to it?

Comment: I just used mpi.h math.h fstream and iostream libraries in my code

Comment: post your link line, somewhere you (or your `Makefile`) is adding  `-lcr` to `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Im not a programmer Im master student of physics what must I do please say step by step.thanks

Comment: we are not mind readers, you have to help us help you. Your problem is the linker (`/usr/bin/ld`) is telling you it cannot find a library you've instructed it to link against. You haven't given any details about your environment outside of Ubuntu Linux 11.04. Updating your question with how you build your program will be helpful. Using correct punctuation, capitalization, etc will also draw more responses to your question.

Comment: As a student, you may have access to resources more tailored to your needs than this generic Internet site. You could ask your adviser, for example. Or you could consult the IT help desk in charge of maintaining the development environment of your college's lab computers. There might be special configurations that no one here would know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `usr/bin/ld :cannot find -lcr`

Googling around [shows](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich-discuss/2011-July/010328.html) the `cr` library is provided by the [Berkeley Lab Checkpoint Restart](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libcr0) (BLCR) package. I think you need to install it.